# Direction of steepest descent and minimization?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have the following linear function: 
$min$ 1/2 $<x, x>$ + $r^Tx$ 
for every x belonging to $R^n$, $r^Tx$ belongs to $R^n$

Now,  = $x^TAy$ and A is symmetric positive definite.  = $x^TAy$ is the scalar product in $R^n$ and the dimensions of A are n$x$n. 
The task is to derive a linear function for x, i.e. solve the linear optimization problem. From what I understand, I need to solve the above-mentioned function for , i.e. for $x^TAy$. Solving it for $x^TAy$ is just a standard quadratic minimization problem, but I am concerned for the y, i.e. a different variable.

And how can I show that x is perpendicular to the kernel of $r^T$. It is given that ker($r^T)x$ belongs to $R^n$ such that $r^Tx = 0$?

Comment: Your code needs some tidying up, I would write it as $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + r^T x$.

Comment: You can see that $y$ is not a separate variable, it's just in the definition of the inner product.  It goes away when the problem is rewritten as I did above.

Comment: Well, not just the code, but also the question itself needs some fixing. 1) $r^Tx$ does not belong to $R^n$, 2) what does it mean to solve a problem for $x^TAy$, when there is only an $x$ as the argument of the function to minimise.

Comment: $r^Tx$ is a functional, i.e., it takes values in $R^n$ and gives a value in $R$.  The inner product is *defined* using $x$ and $y$, but in the objective it is called using $x$ twice, so $y$ does not appear in the minimization problem.

Comment: Sorry for messing up the code. In fact, it was the first time I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is $$ \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) = \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2} x^T A x + r^T x,$$ which has gradient $$ \nabla f(x) = A x + r.$$  The necessary condition $\nabla f(x_*)=0$ gives us that $Ax_*=-r$, which has a unique solution.  Since the Hessian $A$ is positive definite we are guaranteed the existence and uniqueness of the solution to $A x_* = -r$, and that the point $x_*$ is a minimizer.

In the latter part of your question, do you mean perpendicular in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or perpendicular w.r.t. your inner product, i.e., $<x_*,\ker(r)>=x_*^T A \ker(r) = 0$?  Perhaps knowing $x_* = -A^{-1} r$ is enough to let you finish the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I mean perpendicular in $R^n$, I should have clarified it or written it properly